# Why is strnlen() not considered for inclusion in C23?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c-strings, c23

Functions `strdup()` and `strndup()` have finally made it into the upcoming C23 Standard:

> **7.24.6.4 The `strdup` function**
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
> #include <string.h>
> char *strdup(const char *s);
> ```
>
> The `strdup` function creates a copy of the string pointed to by `s` in a space allocated as if by a call to `malloc`.
>
> **Returns**
> The `strdup` function returns a pointer to the first character of the duplicate string. The returned pointer can be passed to `free`. If no space can be allocated the `strdup` function returns a null pointer.
>
> **7.24.6.5 The `strndup` function**
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
> #include <string.h>
> char *strndup(const char *s, size_t size);
> ```
>
> The `strndup` function creates a string initialized with no more than `size` initial characters of the array pointed to by `s` and up to the first null character, whichever comes first, in a space allocated as if by a call to `malloc`. If the array pointed to by `s` does not contain a null within the first `size` characters, a null is appended to the copy of the array.
>
> **Returns**
> The `strndup` function returns a pointer to the first character of the created string. The returned pointer can be passed to `free`. If no space can be allocated the `strndup` function returns a null pointer.

Why was the POSIX-2008 function `strnlen` not considered for inclusion?

```
#include <string.h>
size_t strnlen(const char *s, size_t maxlen);
```

The `strnlen()` function shall compute the smaller of the number of bytes in the array to which `s` points, not including the terminating NUL character, or the value of the `maxlen` argument. The `strnlen()` function shall never examine more than `maxlen` bytes of the array  pointed to by `s`.

Comment: Hmm, so `strndup()` allocates up to `size + 1` bytes (I expected `size` or call it `maxlen`) and `strnlen()` returns up to `size`?  Such `n` functions are useful yet a little fuzzy on the extremes cases.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: `strndup(s, n)` allocates at least `strnlen(s, n) + 1` bytes. This is consistent with `strncat(s1, s2, n)` copying `strnlen(s2, n)` bytes from `s2` and adding a null terminator. The *fuzzy* one is `strncpy` of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesingly, this function was proposed in https://www9.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n2351.htm

It was discussed at the London meeting in 2019. See the agenda:
https://www9.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n2370.htm

The discussion minutes can be found at https://www9.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n2377.pdf.
Page 59.

It was rejected due to no consensus.

> 6.33 Sebor, Add strnlen to C2X [N 2351]
>
> ...
>
> *Straw poll: Should N2351 be put into C2X?
>
> (11/6/6)
>
> Not clear consensus.

As result the function was not added.

Comment: Considering the gazillion new floating point names added, namespace pollution cannot be invoked, especially since `strnlen` is a reserved name anyway.

Comment: @chqrlie Re: "no consensus": FYI: the "Annex K: Fix or deprecate" ended as "[Deprecate/Fix/Abstain: 6/6/5](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2307.pdf)". So, "no consensus, keep it untouched".

Comment: @pmor: the committee is so conservative on some aspects. Annex K cannot be *fixed*: the Microsoft semantics are inconsistent and cumbersome, yet the only implementation with significant usage is theirs, and they are unlikely to change those semantics... so removing Annex K and making these functions a proprietary extension is the only choice IMHO.

Comment: @chqrlie Re: "Annex K cannot be fixed": 6 people don't think so. I personally found many issues while implementing some of the Annex K functions. Then started reading about "why Annex K is flawed / unfinished". Found defect reports, Red Hat [proposal](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm) to remove it, and finally the "6/6/5".

Answer (score 1):

One argument against `strnlen` is that it's a superfluous function, since we already have `memchr`. Example:

```
const char str[666] = "hello world";
size_t length1 = strnlen(str,666);
size_t length2 = (char*)memchr(str,'\0',666) - str;
```

Advantages of `memchr`:

- Already been a standard C function since the dawn of time.
- Possibly more efficient than `strnlen` in some situations(?).
- More generic API.
- `memchr` already ought to be in use for the purpose of sanitising supposed string input before calling functions like `strcpy`, so what purpose `strnlen` fills is unclear.
- Has proper error handling, unlike `strnlen` which does not tell if it failed or not.

Disadvantages:

- More awkward and type-unsafe interface for the purpose of finding a string length specifically.

Comment: `length2 = (char*)memchr(str,'\0',666) - str;` would have undefined behavior if `str` does not have a null terminator at all, whereas `strnlen()` can be passed a non null terminated array as long as the size argument is at most the length of the array.

Comment: @chqrlie Yeah well, my example doesn't have error handling for that. But now that you mention it, that's actually yet another strong argument for _not_ using `strnlen` - it doesn't report errors. Illustration: https://godbolt.org/z/dhfE6P38v

Comment: passing an array without a null terminator in the first `n` bytes is not an error. Bytes beyond the first `n` should not be examined. The argument does not have to be a null terminated string.  The same semantics are used for `strncat`: *The `strncat` function appends not more than `n` characters (a null character and characters that follow it are not appended) from the array pointed to by `s2` to the end of the string pointed to by `s1`.*

Comment: @chqrlie Yes but my point is that if you use `memchr` you get error handling for free. Whereas `strnlen` cannot be used for input sanitation. And in case you do know that the input string is proper, you might as well use `strlen` since it's faster than `strnlen`.

Comment: It looks like `strnlen` can be used for input sanitation. A string sitting in a buffer of size `N` cannot possibly have length of `N`. If `strnlen` returns `N`, you know the buffer contains something that is not a string.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Yeah that's true. But either way, I see no advantage of using `strnlen` over `memchr`. (Also micro-optimization, a check vs zero might be a tiny bit faster than comparing two integers for equivalence.)

Comment: @Lundin: pushing your argument, `strlen` is useless since you can use `memchr(p, '\0', -1) - p`, or better `strchr(p, '\0') - p`, `strcpy` can be replaced with `memcpy(dest, src, strlen(src) + 1)`...

Comment: @chqrlie Those examples are a bit ridiculous, but truth is that many C programmers are brainwashed to always use certain functions for certain tasks. Consider `str1 = malloc(strlen(str2)+1); strcpy(str1, str2);` This code is needlessly slow, because the programmer can't think outside the box. If we know the string length, then why use slow `strcpy`? It could be optimized as `size_t n = strlen(str2)+1; str1 = malloc(n); memcpy(str1, str2, n);` Just as readable, only faster.

Comment: @Lundin: Good example! Of course `str1 = strdup(str2);` is even more readable, just as fast, less error prone, fully defined and usable directly as a function argument. Too bad it took so long for the C Standard to include simple POSIX utility functions.

Comment: @chqrlie Yep, a correctly implemented strdup ought to boil down to inlining of strlen+malloc+memcpy.